# Programatically paste text into text box in another application

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to be able to paste the results from my application to another application.  Been Googling and all I can find is the [ApplicationCommands.Paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.paste(v=vs.110).aspx).  That will paste it into my application not another application.

Background:  My application needs to interact with a very old application.  This application is not being developed and **DOES NOT** have any API calls. Meaning any answers like "Link your application via DLLs" will only be excepted if it also includes a time machine :P So the solution is to simple paste results from my app to the old application.

For workflow reasons the client wants my Application to disappear and automatically paste the results into an open text box in (if it fails then manually pasting the results in).

Hiding the window is simple, but how do I find current active application and then paste it in?  Is this even possible?  Also note this application is **NOT** .NET (VB 6 if I am correct).

Comment: You're looking for "copy" not "paste" to grab the data from your application.

Comment: When you say "...into an open text box in (if it fails...", is there a word missing after "in"? Is the other application an existing application that you can't modify?

Comment: You might be able to get a handle to the text window and use WM_SETTEXT.

Comment: @roryap I want to copy from my app and paste it into another app.  So I want do a "paste" command to another app

Comment: @EdPlunkett That is correct, I cannot modify and it will not be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bring up the other app and send a key combination... something like:

```
[DllImport ("User32.dll")]
static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

public static void PasteToApplication(string appName)
{
  var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(appName).FirstOrDefault();
  if(proc != null)
  {
    var handle = proc.MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(handle);
    SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
  }
}
```

This should bring up the other app's window and send a ctrl-v command. With a bit of experimentation, you could find out the exact handle of the control you want to send the paste to, and set focus on it aswell

Comment: This looks like what I want, two questions: SendKeys is from System.Windows.Forms, My app is WPF so I don't have access to it.  What is the WPF command?  How can I find out the appName in Windows or do I have to hardcode it?

Comment: @Xaphann you can include the windows.forms reference in your project, `SendKeys` should work without an app domain (it's just a simple wrapper against the windows API). The `appName` should be the name of the app you want to paste on, as shown by the Task Manager (generally, the name of the application excluding `.exe`). `GetProcessesByName` returns an array of processes: if the name of your app is common then you'll have to figure out how to find it (via the process executable path or something).

Comment: Also, this just opens the main window in your other application: this may not be the case if you want to paste to a secondary form or something... but we don't have enough info about your other application to give a definitive answer: the premise is: find the handle of the window you want to bring up (or find the handle of the precise control and set it active using the Windows API), then send the control-v key combination. I just showed one way to do it, but your mileage may vary depending on the particularities of the app you are going to paste the data on

Comment: Thanks that answered my questions!