# How do I copy text from a c# Application to Notepad.exe under Windows 11?

Tags: c#, clipboard, notepad

I am using the following code to copy text from a c# application to Notepad.exe:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

    private void btnShowLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        var notepad = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        notepad.WaitForInputIdle();

        while (notepad == null && count < 20)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            count++;
        }

        Clipboard.SetText(txbLog.Text);
        SendMessage(FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null), 0x000C, 0, txbLog.Text);
    }
```

For **Windows 10** this works fine.

For **Windows 11** it does not. Notepad is opened, but no text is paste.

I think, this is because in Windows 11 Tabs were added to Notepad so that the internal structure of the program was changed.

Does anybody know how I have to change my code so that it works for Windows 11?

Edit: The code in the answers of the linked questions does not work either. I'm getting the desired result for Windows 10, but not for Windows 11.

Comment: The code only worked by accident. `SendMessage(FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null), 0x000C, 0, txbLog.Text)` doesn't try to paste anything, it tries to find the edit box of the Notepad application and send the `WM_SETTEXT` to it - that's what `0x000C` is

Comment: If you really wanted to use the Clipboard, an easy way would be to bring Notepad to the front `BringWindowToTop(notepad.Handle)` and call `SendKeys("^V")` - the keyboard shortcut for `Paste`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tested both answers and none of them worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272433/programatically-paste-text-into-text-box-in-another-application

With this code I don't even get a handle.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646605/how-to-paste-text-using-windows-paste-command-to-other-application-in-c

I can open Notepad, I'm getting a handle, the Notepad Window is put to front, but it remains empty.